# Need Help Translating from VBA to C# Selenium

Tags: c#, vba, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to convert some code from VBA in Excel to C# Selenium and I'm struggling with the VBA verbiage. The VBA code parses a dropdown menu on a website like this:

```
Set b = a.contentDocument.getElementsByTagName("frame")("iframe_tier1")
Set c = a.contentDocument.getElementsByTagName("frame")("iframe_tier2")

For Each Ele In b.contentDocument.getElementsByTagName("select")("selectDropdownItem")
    If Ele.Value = "xxxx" Then
        Ele.Selected = True
        Exit For
    End If

Next
```

I'm trying to understand the second argument in the getElementsByTagName (ex. ("select")("selectDropdownItem"))

Is the second item ("selectDropdownItem") a second argument? The C# doesn't seem to want to allow something like:

```
myDriver.FindElements(By.TagName("select", "selectDropdownItem"));
```

I've also tried:

```
IList<IWebElement> myElements = myDriver.FindElements(By.TagName("select")("selectDropdownItem"));
foreach(IWebElement ele in myElements)
{
MessageBox.Show(ele.Text);
}
```

Each time I get an error saying TagName cannot accept multiple arguments. What is the second item in ("") in the VBA and how I can convert that to C#?

Comment: I don't recognize that syntax and can't imagine what it might be. Rather than trying to "convert" it, let's just rewrite it. Please post the relevant HTML for the SELECT. Additionally, a link to the page itself would be helpful as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below will take care of the `For Each` loop in the code you provided.

```
SelectElement dropdown = new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("select")));
dropdown.SelectByValue("xxxx");
```

The part I'm unsure about is the `Set b` line. I'm not sure if that's supposed to switch to an IFRAME or ??? If so, you'll need to adapt the code below, providing a locator for the relevant IFRAME/FRAME tag.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.FrameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.CssSelector("frame"))); // if needed, update locator for IFRAME/FRAME

SelectElement dropdown = new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("select"))); // if needed, update locator for SELECT (not OPTION tags)
dropdown.SelectByValue("xxxx");

// once you are done with the elements inside the IFRAME/FRAME, switch back to the main page content
driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
```

If you need help with locators, update your question with the relevant HTML for the IFRAME/FRAME and the SELECT and I'll update the code.